# API Component Separation

Tags: php, api

I'm new to the world of API programming, I just have a bit of a side project at work at the moment and I'm learning as I write, so bear with me.

I'm unsure as to the best way to implement an API for multiple different functions. At the moment I just have a test script I run and an apache redirect that redirects anything under /api to this script, call it TestAPI.php (so /api/anything will redirect). I pass the path variable of the API to the script (so in that example the path would be 'anything').

At the moment I'm just writing it for 1 purpose, to look up some data based on the path, and eventually be about to update and delete etc with PUT/DELETE etc (it's restISH not restFUL). This is fine at the moment where everything redirects to this script, but what about if I need 2 different functions? So I want to look up a different data set? So for example now /api/data1 would go to the 1st set and /api/data2 would go to the second. This is where I start to get unsure.

Do I simply have 1 mega script that grows and grows so that /api/data1 and /api/data2 redirect to the  same place (and thus handle any errors like 404s there). Or do I have a script for /api/data1 and /api/data2 with separate redirects to each, then a generic catchall for 404s (I would always like to return JSON/XML rather than HTML for a 404, so I need at least logic to return based on the Accept header).

As a 3rd option, do I have some sort of frontline controller that catches everything, then calls off to the sub components? So 1 script that is redirects to for anything under /api, which then calls off to the required components or 404s if it's an invalid path. This seems like the best way to do it to me, but I have no idea how. Do I have some section of the site that only that script can call, or do I use cURL from the frontline controller to the back end API sections (as I'd need to pass POST/PUT data I assume I'd have to use cURL, is there any other way?). How is this best implemented in Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you use a front controller. The front controller can use convention like first thing after /api processes the request
i.e.

/api/firstprocessor/method1

/api/firstprocessor/method2

/api/secondprocessor/method14

You can check out Zend_Framework for an example of this in action, or it can be something as simple as

```
$name = 'Script_' . $this->generateCommandName($request->getPathVariable(1));
$this->executeScript($name, $request);

public function executeScript($class, Request $request) {
    if (file_exists("scripts/".$class.'.php')) {

        //include the script
    require_once "scripts/".$class.'.php';

    //execute the script
    $command = new $class;
    $command->execute($request);
    }
}
```

Then all your scripts just have an execute method that uses $request to get $_GET or $_POST variables

Comment: Okay, so the front controller doesn't actually call another API section via the webserver but rather executes the script for that section (like data1 using the above example) within it's own execution process?

Comment: yeah, that's a pretty standard way of doing it

Comment: Okay great, that gives me plenty to mull on. Thanks.